# Won't display cities and similar on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I write a code for showing places with places api but when i type etc"Paris France" code wont to show location.

DEMO: [Here is the link](http://jsbin.com/ayugun/57#)

CODE: [Here is code](http://jsbin.com/ayugun/57/edit)

All work fine but when I type etc "Paris, France" (autocomplete) the api don't show anything

Is there any solution how to solve that?

(sorry for my english is bad, but i'm learning hard)

Comment: I try to run Demo and it seems okay to me, i can see paris , france and its working :)

Comment: when type , map show you paris?

Comment: I try but when I type paris center of map is go on center of pacific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well...the center is just over the pacific ocean...

try to make a map.setCenter() to the point.

```
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(17);
        }
```

Comment: there are 2 comments *EDIT 1* and *EDIT 2* ;)